# Retrieve ScannerSubscription results using IbPy

Tags: python, interactive-brokers, ibpy

I'm struggling with the results of a `ScannerSubscription`.
For example, if I request:

```
qqq_id = 0
subscript = ScannerSubscription()
subscript.numberOfRows(15)
subscript.m_scanCode = 'HIGH_OPEN_GAP'
subscript.m_instrument = 'STK'
subscript.m_averageOptionVolumeAbove = ''
subscript.m_couponRateAbove = ''
subscript.m_couponRateBelow = ''
subscript.m_abovePrice = '5'
subscript.m_belowPrice = ''
subscript.m_marketCapAbove = ''
subscript.m_marketCapBelow = ''
subscript.m_aboveVolume = '100000'
subscript.m_stockTypeFilter = 'ALL'
subscript.locationCode('STK.US.MAJOR')
tws_conn.reqScannerSubscription(qqq_id, subscript)
tws_conn.reqScannerParameters()
```

I received a `scannerData` response like this:

`<scannerData reqId=0, rank=0, contractDetails=<ib.ext.ContractDetails.ContractDetails object at 0x00000000036EFA58>, distance=None, benchmark=None, projection=None, legsStr=None>`
etc...

But I cannot retrieve the result values, for example:

`reqScannerParameters()` xml result specifies `<colId>390</colId>` as the colId for the `Gap` value:

```
<ScanType>
    <displayName>Top Close-to-Open % Gainers</displayName>
    <scanCode>HIGH_OPEN_GAP</scanCode>
    <instruments>STK,STOCK.NA,STOCK.EU,STOCK.HK,FUT.US,FUT.HK,FUT.EU,FUT.NA</instruments>
    <absoluteColumns>false</absoluteColumns>
<Columns varName="columns">
<Column>
    <colId>390</colId>
    <name>Gap</name>
    <display>true</display>
    <section>m</section>
    <displayType>DATA</displayType>
</Column>
```

How do I retrieve the GAP value?
Is this even possible ?

Comment: Just a guess, but after you get the contract in the scannerData callback, use it to request a snapshot with reqMktData.  You can then calculate the open gap.

Comment: @brian That was my first approach, but I'm trying to avoid any extra requests and calculations,  it doesn't make sense, ib api should return the values. Thank you anyway.

Comment: I just read some comments at yahoo TWS API group and others have mentioned you generally have to request data as you just get the bare minimum back in scannerData.

Comment: I think you're talking about https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/TWSAPI/conversations/topics/36685 . It seems that we need to issue a `reqMktData` and parse the tick_types in order to calculate the gap and other values... This sucks!

Comment: Similar to that.  Note that if your scan code data type needs something other than regular data, you can't use snapshots.  That example was about requesting all kinds of exotic tick types.  The open gap can be calculated just from open =tick type 14, close = tt 9 .  Those should both come from a basic reqMktData.  Maybe try after the holidays though.

Comment: I've posted in a couple on a thread, let's see what's the feedback. I'll probably end up calculating the gap as you said, If so, I'll let you know so you can make your comment an answer! tks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I'm sure you're supposed to request data after getting the contract.

```
import pandas as pd
scans = 15
res = pd.DataFrame(index = range(scans), columns = ['sym','open','close','calc']).fillna(0)
msgs = []

from ib.ext.Contract import Contract
from ib.opt import ibConnection, message
from ib.ext.TickType import TickType as tt

def tickPrice(msg):
    global scans 

    if msg.field in [tt.OPEN, tt.CLOSE]:
        res.loc[msg.tickerId,tt.getField(msg.field)] = msg.price

    op = res.loc[msg.tickerId,'open']
    cl = res.loc[msg.tickerId,'close']

    if  op > 0 and cl > 0 and res.loc[msg.tickerId,'calc'] == 0:
        res.loc[msg.tickerId,'calc'] = ((op-cl)*100/cl)
        con.cancelMktData(msg.tickerId)
        scans -= 1
        if scans == 0:
            print(res)
            con.disconnect()

def snapshot(msg):
    res.loc[msg.rank,'sym'] = msg.contractDetails.m_summary.m_symbol
    #tt.OPEN (14) isn't coming with snapshot
    con.reqMktData(str(msg.rank), msg.contractDetails.m_summary, "", False)

def watcher(msg):
    #print (msg)
    msgs.append(msg)

def scanData(msg):
    snapshot(msg)

def scanDataEnd(msg):
    con.cancelScannerSubscription(qqq_id)

con = ibConnection(port=7497, clientId=888)
con.registerAll(watcher)
con.unregister(watcher, message.scannerData)
con.register(scanData, message.scannerData)
con.unregister(watcher, message.scannerDataEnd)
con.register(scanDataEnd, message.scannerDataEnd)
con.unregister(watcher, message.tickPrice)
con.register(tickPrice, message.tickPrice)

con.connect()

from ib.ext.ScannerSubscription import ScannerSubscription
qqq_id = 0
subscript = ScannerSubscription()
subscript.numberOfRows(15)
subscript.m_scanCode = 'HIGH_OPEN_GAP'
subscript.m_instrument = 'STK'
subscript.m_averageOptionVolumeAbove ='0'
subscript.m_abovePrice = '5'
subscript.m_aboveVolume = '100000'

con.reqScannerSubscription(qqq_id, subscript)
```

res at 1 pm est =

```
        sym   open  close       calc
0       TAC   4.95   4.25  16.470588
1      CTRP  44.80  40.99   9.294950
2      IIIN  39.26  36.58   7.326408
3       LFC  14.60  13.63   7.116654
4       ACH  11.59  10.87   6.623735
5      KALV   9.01   8.38   7.517900
6      OMER  13.25  12.75   3.921569
7      DWTI  68.00  66.50   2.255639
8      WLDN  23.75  23.43   1.365770
9       BZQ  19.67  18.73   5.018687
10     JNUG   6.55   6.43   1.866252
11  GXP PRB  50.78  49.80   1.967871
12       AU  10.85  10.59   2.455146
13     USLV  13.07  12.81   2.029664
14      CBD  16.60  16.03   3.555833
```

I don't know why they don't come in rank order??

Comment: I guess we've to sort the results after calculation the `gap`. It worked, appreciated!